# Include header and footer using Spring boot and thymeleaf on html file on hierarchical folder append hierarchy on the CSS link on head tag?

Tags: java, css, layout, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have include the header and footer as fragments for the html using **Spring Boot** and **Thymeleaf**. The header and footer works fine for the index.html but doesn't work for the other *.html pages which are maintained on the hierarchical folder. So, the urls for CSS and other Script linked in the html are changed due to hierarchical urls.

For example:

[image]

```
<-- header.html -->
<head th:fragment="header">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title th:text="${title}"></title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" th:href="@{images/favicon.png}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" /> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{css/style.css}" />
</head>

<-- footer.html -->
<div th:fragment="footer">
    <footer class="footer">
        <div class="container">
            <p class="text-muted">&copy; 2017 | Attendance</p>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <script type="text/javascript"
    src="webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</div>

<-- index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head lang="en" th:include="fragments/header :: header">
</head>
<body>
    <div lang="en" th:include="fragments/navigation :: navigation"></div>

    <div class="container">
         <div class="jumbotron text-center">
            <h1 th:text="'Welcome To ' + ${name}"></h1>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div lang="en" th:include="fragments/footer :: footer"></div>
 </body>
 </html>

<-- edit.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head lang="en" th:include="fragments/header :: header">
</head>
<body>
    <div lang="en" th:include="fragments/navigation :: navigation"></div>

    <div class="container" id="userDiv">
    <h3>User Form</h3>
    <hr></hr>
    <form id="userform" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4" role="form"
        th:action="@{/user/update}" method="post"
        enctype="multipart/form-data" th:object="${useredit}">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="firstname">First Name</label> <input type="text"
                class="form-control" id="firstname" name="firstname"
                th:field="${useredit.firstname}" placeholder="First Name" />
        </div>


        <div>
            <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="field" name="field"
                th:field="${useredit.id}" placeholder="Id" />
            <p>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
            </p>
        </div>
    </form>
    </div>

    <div lang="en" th:include="fragments/footer :: footer"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

I have this method on controller, its url is "http://localhost:8080/user/edit/1". And the CSS urls must be "http://localhost:8080/css/style.css".

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/edit/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String useredit(Model model, @PathVariable long id) {
    model.addAttribute("title", "Attendance | User");
    model.addAttribute("user", new User());
    model.addAttribute("useredit", userModel.findOne(id));

    return "/user/edit";
}
```

Instead of the "http://localhost:8080/css/style.css" the browser returns url as "http://localhost:8080/user/edit/css/style.css". So, the browser cannot find the css file. But works for the index.html file which is not inside any hierarchical folder.

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a problem with relative versus absolute path to me.

In your header and footer include, you need to refer to the CSS file by its absolute path from the root, `/css/style.css` and include the `th:href` attribute as well, e.g. `th:href="@{/css/style.css}"`

If I recall correctly, you may also need a config file with your Thymeleaf setup that specifies where the static files are served from. See also [Loading static resources with Spring Boot and Thymeleaf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27869267/loading-static-resources-with-spring-boot-and-thymeleaf)

Comment: No thats not the problem, when i include the header.html to the other html pages the linked urls are appended with the hierarchy of the pages.          For example: the url is given as "http://localhost:8080/css/style.css" to the /index.html but the browser returns url as "http://localhost:8080/user/edit/css/style.css" for the /user/edit/{id}.

Comment: can't see your example, can you add it to the OP?

Comment: Please see the question again, i have given certain part of codes as an example. Help me!

Comment: yes, so like I said, your code has a relative path to the CSS, but you need an absolute path, like this `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/css/style.css}" />`