# o.s.boot.context.web.ErrorPage: Cannot forward to error page for request [/] as the response has already been committed

Tags: spring-boot

I keep getting a blank page when I render this application in tomcat 8. The only error I see is:

```
o.s.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter: Cannot forward to error page for 
request [/] as the response has already been committed.
```

Therefore my issue is I am unable to render the index.html page.

I took a static page and added a spring-boot module in it. Ever since I made the change I have not been able to render the page again. I have the index.html file under `templates`

[image]

I added comments in my controller to see if they are even being hit and they are not:

```
@Controller
public class ApplicationController {


    @Autowired
    ContactService contactService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/", method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public String contactForm() throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Inside GET in Application Controller");

        //model.addAttribute("contact", new Contact());

        return "index";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/contact", method= RequestMethod.POST)
    public String contactSubmit() throws IOException {

        System.out.println("Inside POST in Application Controller");

        return "index";
    }


}
```

I was using Thymeleaf but decided against it which is why the parameters in the methods are blank.

I have uploaded the project to GIT to make it easier for someone to poke around and download if so desired.

[Project on GIT](https://github.com/drewjocham/stidham_financial.git)

----------------Update 1----------------------

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(WebConfig.class);

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("index");
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

        registry.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);

        registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/css/");

        registry.addResourceHandler("/images/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/images/");

        registry.addResourceHandler("/image/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/image/");

        registry.addResourceHandler("/javascripts/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/javascripts/");

    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

}
```

There is really nothing else to show that I can think of. You can look at it on GIT for the other files if you so choose too.

Comment: Do not put your index.html file to templates. it's usually in the webapp directory or served under `static` directory. See https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot ,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27583278/spring-boot-spring-mvc-thymeleaf-apache-tiles. http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-spring-mvc.html

Comment: @AntonNovopashin I have tried that too. I just moved it into the static folder and it is still having the same behavior.

Comment: Please share your configuration. Controller is not enough. Spring MVC has a couple configuration parameters `spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/`
`spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp`. But usually for the static page you don't have to do that. The Boot example https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-jsp or https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-static

Comment: @AntonNovopashin please see update 1

Comment: Your Git hub link is no longer working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was playing with your application. (git repository helped to solve your configuration issues).

The problem was your mix of configuration properties and annotations.
The following steps will help to restore `default` Spring Boot behavior.

1. Move your `index.htm` to the `webapp` directory.
2. Copy all files from `webapp/resources` to the `webapp`
3. Remove the following configuration property - `spring.mvc.static-path-pattern=/resources/*`
4. Delete mapping to the `/` `@RequestMapping(value="/", method= RequestMethod.GET)` and the method itself. Boot will handle the `index.html` mapping to the `ROOT`. `/` mapping confused Boot Spring MVC auto configuration.
5. You can delete your `WebConfig` completely.

The next step would be to map static resource as you want:

```
public class AppMvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
  @Override
  public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    // Including all static resources.

    registry.addResourceHandler("/assets/**", 
              "/css/**", 
              "/img/**",
              "/js/**"
         ).addResourceLocations("/assets/",
              "/css/", 
              "/img/",
              "/js/"
    ).resourceChain(true)
     .addResolver(new PathResourceResolver());

     super.addResourceHandlers(registry);
  }
}
```

See my git [repository](https://github.com/antonevane/StidhamFinancial).

See more information about custom [Spring MVC configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html).

Answer (score 6):

Methods `contactForm()` and `contactSubmit()` return `String`,
try to use `@RestController` instead of `@Controller`
It fix my problem

Answer (score 4):

There may be possibility that you are missing '@ResponseBody' on your method.
for an example

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/myMethod", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=application/json") 
@ResponseBody 
public String myMethod(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
{ 
    // some business logic

    retutn "Hi" 
}
```