# Config two controllers

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have two controllers.

I wrote this controllers and where i have to write config to correct work.

```
@Controller

public class BookController {

    private BookService bookService;

    @Autowired(required = true)
    @Qualifier(value = "bookService")
    public void setBookService(BookService bookService) {
        this.bookService = bookService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "books", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listBooks(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("book", new Book());
        model.addAttribute("listBooks", this.bookService.listBooks());

        return "books";
    }

}

@Controller("controller1")
public class AuthorController {
        private AuthorService  authorService;

        @Autowired(required = true)
        @Qualifier(value = "authorService")
        public void setBookService(AuthorService authorService) {
            this.authorService = authorService;
        }

        @RequestMapping
        (value = "authors", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String listAuthors(Model model){
           model.addAttribute("author", new Author());
           model.addAttribute("listAuthors", this.authorService.list());

           return "";
        }
    }
```

Comment: You don't need to write configuration. You just need `@Controller` annotation, and have component scan in your `dispatcher-servlet.xml`. Check if you have this `<context:component-scan base-package="path.to.your.controllers"/>` in your xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Xml based configuration try add this config to your dispatcherServlet.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example.controllers"/>
```

and if you use Java based config the add this code to your WebMvcConfigurerAdapter implementation config class

```
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example.controllers")
```

Example:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example.controllers")
public class SpringConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }
    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }
}
```

Comment: Will it be work for two controllers? Sorry for stupid question but I'm realy bad know this technology.

Comment: Of course. You can declare controllers in same package as much as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I believe that it will be enough to add

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

into a `pom.xml` and add an `@EnableWebMvc` annotation into you `AppConfig` file

**UPD**
Let's say you have an application `com.foo.app.AppName`
Then to solve the problem you must create a class `com.foo.app.AppName.AppConfig` and add at least this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
}
```

It's not an iron rule to implement `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` - you can use any configurers depends of ypu needs

Comment: I must just replace @Controller at @EnableWebMvc?

Comment: @Jackson750 no. Somwhere in you project must be placed a configuration file that is a main config file of the project. I'll update my answer to clarify this case

Comment: Ok, I will be waitting for your answer

Comment: What must be inside that class? I just don't saw that costruction before.

Comment: Nothing have to be there. Just try to create it I've showed below.

Answer (score 0):

You could autowire services like this:

```
    @Controller
    @RequestMapping("book")
    public class BookController {

        @Autowired
        private BookService bookService;

        @GetMapping("find_all")
        public String list(Model model) {
            model.addAttribute("book", bookService.findAll());
            return "book/list";
        }
```

Comment: Type Status Report

Message /books

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Comment: 404 Not found  so...?

Comment: The return of the controller method ("book/list") is a path to some .html file, so you gotta have this "book" as a folder and a "list.html" as a file. All of these has to be inside of resources folder.

Comment: And I hope you are using the template engine (thymeleaf).

Comment: Look this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27583278/spring-boot-spring-mvc-thymeleaf-apache-tiles/27680210#27680210) the image in the beginning of the question, pay attention in the hierarchy